# Compute a derivative within limits in Maxima

Tags: derivative, maxima

I want to compute a derivative in maxima within certain limits. Goals is to create exercises for integrals. These integrals do have limits, so i would like to go the other way round, so i need to find a way to define a derivative that exists wihtin the same limits. Is there a maxima function for that?

Comment: Please provide a simple example of what you have and what you want to do and the expected result.